# Robust way to resolve a DNS address in a script (IPv4 (A) and IPv6 (AAAA))?

Tags: domain-name-system, bash, shell-scripting

I have a domain name in a bash variable (`$TARGET`), and I want to get the IPv4 (`A` record) address of it in my bash script (I also want to get the IPv6 `AAAA` record (if exists)), in a *robust* manner.

i.e. What bash/unix command will: (i) print the IP address (and *only* the IP address) of the DNS resolution (ii) print nothing to stdout (or non-zero exit) if there is no DNS record for that domain found (iii) allow me to choose to ask for `A` or `AAAA` record.

`host "$TARGET"` prints lots of human readable stuff, and I'm reluctant to parse that.

`dig +short` looked promising, but in some scenarios, it also prints other warning messages which I do not understand, or care about.

```bash
$ dig +short -t A "$TARGET"
;; Warning: Client COOKIE mismatch
1.2.3.4
```

Debian test/bookworm. Bash v5.2 (installed via apt)

Comment: I think that might be better for stackoverflow.com due the programming relevance?

Comment: I am asking about a unix command to resolve DNS.

Comment: Note: there are some subtle differences in how your system can resolve a specific host (i.e. how `/etc/hosts` typically had precedence over DNS). Do you want the same IP that `ping` would send packets to, in other words the results the system resolver finds, or a DNS  record, ignoring /etc/hosts and other sources? And how do you want to deal with round-robin/multi-valued records.

Answer (score 11):

I'm unsure if you want to actually query nameservers or rather rely on your system's name resolution:

```bash
$ getent ahosts one.one.one.one. | awk '{ print $1 }' | sort -u
1.0.0.1
1.1.1.1
2606:4700:4700::1001
2606:4700:4700::1111
$ getent ahosts nonexistent.host | awk '{ print $1 }' | sort -u
$ getent ahosts www.what-is-my-ipv4.com | awk '{ print $1 }' | sort -u
185.26.156.187
```

You can also make it return v4 or v6 addresses with `ahostsv4` and `ahostsv6`.

If you just use `hosts`, you are subject to your `/etc/gai.conf`'s settings.

Found this on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212897/nslookup-dig-firefox-ignoring-etc-hosts-file-entries:

> `nslookup`, `dig`, and `host` are tools for querying DNS name servers.
>
> If your configuration is not provided by a name server (like the
> information given in /etc/hosts) those tools will not show them,
> because they directly ask the name server.
>
> If you want to check that the "usual" resolution is working (i.e. the
> way specified in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`) you can use `getent`:
>
> ```
> getent hosts www.winaproduct.com
> ```

Comment: Note that `getent hosts` uses your machine's name resolution mechanism, which may or may not be DNS, depending on what is configured in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. Alternative sources of information could include the `/etc/hosts` file, WINS, and multicast DNS, for example. The information could also be subject to caching mechanisms such as `nscd`.

Comment: Which is exactly what "rely on your system's name resolution" (i.e. `getaddrinfo`) means.

Comment: I felt obligated to point that out, because the question asked for DNS resolution.

Answer (score 7):

You are on the right track with `dig`. You can suppress that particular cookie related error (per the man page). Below, I am also choosing to redirect all errors to `/dev/null` just in case, as you wanted failures to be silent.

```
[jg7@comp1 ~]$ TARGET="google.com"

[jg7@comp1 ~]$ dig +short +nobadcookie -t A "$TARGET" @8.8.8.8 2>/dev/null
64.233.177.139
64.233.177.138
64.233.177.101
64.233.177.113
64.233.177.100
64.233.177.102

[jg7@comp1 ~]$ dig +short +nobadcookie -t AAAA "$TARGET" @8.8.8.8 2>/dev/null
2607:f8b0:4002:c08::65
2607:f8b0:4002:c08::8a
2607:f8b0:4002:c08::64
2607:f8b0:4002:c08::71
```

If this isn't what you are looking for, then let me know.

[EDIT] Used a bash variable so as to be closer to the original question.

Answer (score 7):

`getent ahosts[v4|v6]` and generally anything that uses getaddrinfo() is the right answer, as it will use the same name resolution mechanisms (DNS, mDNS, NetBIOS, NIS, LDAP…) as the rest of the system, as well as performing the same suffix search (i.e. resolv.conf `domain`) as the rest of the system.

For example, if getent was not available, you could do:

```
gaiv4="import sys, socket
res = socket.getaddrinfo(sys.argv[1], 0, socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
for e in res: print(e[4][0])"
python -c "$gaiv4" serverfault.com
```

I usually have the ndisc6 package installed for other reasons, and it happens to have `name2addr`:

```
name2addr -m -4 www.google.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for

```
    dig +nocomments +short -t A "$TARGET"
```

or better

```
    dig +noall +short -t A "$TARGET"
```